# create new div to wrap old div when click

Tags: jquery, css

For example existing div is `<div class="two">TWO</div>` when clicked add a new div called `.one` and wrap the `.two` like this `<div class="one"><div class="two">TWO</div></div>` , Any suggestion to do that ? I has tried wrap and prepend.

```js
$(".two").click(function(){
  
  
  $(".one").wrap(this);
});
```

```css
.one{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#ff0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="two">TWO</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, just that the logic was slightly off. You need to call `wrap` from 'two' and not 'one' (the HTML for which is passed to the method):

```js
$(".two").click(function() {
  $(this).wrap("<div class='one'></div>");
});
```

```css
.one {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="two">TWO</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).wrap( "<div class='one'></div>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the div with the class `one` already on the page, just do this:

```
$(".two").click(function(){
  $(this).wrap(".one");
});
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
$('.two').click(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<div class="one"></div>');
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is the guide for jQuery's `.wrap()` function.  It takes in a Selector, htmlString, Element, or jQuery as a parameter.  It can also take a function as a parameter that would return an htmlString or jQuery; but can have a reference to the element it's wrapping something around.